# Problema con CSS > mix-blend-mode: difference;

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, sass

estoy teniendo problemas con el uso de  mix-blend-mode: difference; en CSS. Estoy haciendo un sitio web y usando la librería de animación GSAP.

El caso es que quiero dejar mi logotipo (`<h3 id='logo'>Logotipo</h3>`) por encima del slider (`<div class="slider">`) que hace la animación, y con el atributo CSS mix-blend-mode: difference; , que cambie al color opuesto (que pase el texto de color: white, al color opuesto que sería en este caso negro).

HTML

```
     <header>
        <nav class="top-nav">
            <h3 id='logo'>Logotipo</h3> 
        </nav>
        <section>
            <div class="hero">
                <img src="./img/background.jpg" alt="background">
                <h1 class="headline">Photography</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
    </header>

    <div class="slider">

    </div>
```

El atributo mix-blend-mode se aplica , pero en el momento que hace pasa el slider por encima del logo, este desaparece, y cuando termina la animación del slider vuelve a aparecer con el color opuesto, es decir, se aplica mix-blend-mode.

CSS

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background: #191A1E;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 10vh;
}

#logo{
    font: 24px;
    margin-left: 5rem;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    z-index: 1000000;
    color: #fff;
}

section{
    display: flex;
    height: 80vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.hero{
    height: 60%;
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
}

.hero img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;

}
.slider{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: -1;
}

.headline{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 20%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    font-size: 7vw;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}

.hero::after{
    content: "";
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

JS

```
const hero = document.querySelector('.hero');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const headline = document.querySelector('.headline');

//TimelineMax

const tl = new TimelineMax();


tl.fromTo(hero, 1, {height: '0%'}, {height: '80%', ease: Power2.easeInOut})
.fromTo(hero, 1.2, {width: '100%'}, {width: '80%', ease: Power2.easeInOut})
.fromTo(slider, 1.2, {x: '-100%'}, {x: '0%', ease: Power2.easeInOut}, "-=1.2")
.fromTo(headline, 0.5, {opacity: 0, x: 30}, {opacity: 1, x: 0}, "-=0.7" )
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a solventar este problema?